# c# detect areas in map of country

Tags: c#, detection, area, edge-detection

I have a white map of country with black edges of provinces. I want to recognize areas of provinces and keep pixels of each province. Then I would like to color this areas(as polygon) by different colors. I would be grateful if you could help me. I know that exist AForge.Net library but I didn't find any helpful information.

Comment: can you show us some samples? what have you tried and how did it work?

Comment: I tried edges detection but it only returned me pixels of edges. I am newly in this kind of technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a good binary image by thresholding the original one, you can try 'connected component analysis'. See for example here:
[OpenCV how to find a list of connected components in a binary image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565180/opencv-how-to-find-a-list-of-connected-components-in-a-binary-image)

By a 'good' binary image I mean one where the provinces are completely separated by the black boundaries.