# How can I access components statistics with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently using OpenCV 3.0.0 `connectedComponents()` and `connectedComponentsWithStats()` functions.

I have been trying to access the `statsv(label, COLUMN)` with no luck.

I need to access the connected components' statistics (left, top, area, etc.) and the documentation does not really help much!

Comment: Post your code so we can have a look

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108270/opencv-2-4-10-bwlabel-connected-components/30265609#30265609

Comment: Thank you Marco for your concern.

Comment: Thank you beaker, 
opencv documentation was misleading when stating how statsv matrix is accessed. "Statistics are accessed via statsv(label, COLUMN)".. 

it is instead accessed via statsv.at<int>(label, COLUMN)!!