# Detecting areas of differing colors using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say I have the following image:

[image]

I want to be able to detect each one of the white squares amongst the black background.
I would also like to be able to acquire the center & size of each one.

I'm attempting to use the `opencv` library in C++ in order to achieve this. I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi, with it's standard OS. I installed the latest `opencv` library by running the `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev` command on the terminal. I don't have any prior experience with `opencv` or any of its libraries.

I understand that one can load an image, in the form of it's pixel data, in a variable of type `cv::Mat`. I understand how to access each pixel inside the `cv::Mat` variable, and I understand how to get the byte value for each pixel.

What I'm looking for now is a function or functions that would allow me to detect each one of the white squares, and give me their center positions on the image and their sizes.

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible with `opencv` in C++? Is there a function that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: Sounds like BFS algorithm. Try exploring findContours, drawContours, threshold functions.

Comment: all you have to do is browse opencv docs for the tutorials section. it will teach you how to use the previously mentioned functions (I'd recommend `connectedComponentsWithStats()`). this falls under "do your research". please review [ask]. this isn't a novel or unique problem by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: this is essentially the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75477739/how-to-find-the-average-position-of-pixels-using-numpy-and-cv2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [openCV 2.4.10 bwlabel - connected components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108270/opencv-2-4-10-bwlabel-connected-components)

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic operation of image processing. [It is described in the OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f).

Here's a short bit of code. Please excuse the use of Python. This looks pretty much identical in C++. All the numpy arrays are just `cv::Mat` objects then.

```py
im = cv.imread("ySqre.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
(nlabels, labelmap, stats, centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(im)
```

And the results:

```py
# NOTE: background is counted as a label too, with label index 0
# nlabels: 6 (5 + background)

# centroids:
# array([[320.17971, 160.72618], # this is background, ignore it
#        [ 84.5    ,  56.5    ],
#        [288.5    ,  88.5    ],
#        [437.     , 140.     ],
#        [185.     , 222.5    ],
#        [527.5    , 237.5    ]])

# for the sizes, inspect the `stats` array.
# Use cv.CC_STAT_WIDTH and CC_STAT_HEIGHT for indices into the array.
# There is also the top left corner and the area in number of pixels.

# stats:
# array([[     0,      0,    640,    320, 190359], # background, ignore
#        [    48,     39,     74,     36,   2664],
#        [   274,     62,     30,     54,   1620],
#        [   412,     81,     51,    119,   6069],
#        [   159,    195,     53,     56,   2968],
#        [   514,    218,     28,     40,   1120]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response;
Would it be possible to implement this `opencv` function with a grayscale color threshold, instead of simply detecting all pixels of the same color? So instead of simply identifying completely white (255) pixels, it would identify all areas above a certain brightness level?

Comment: the answer I've given assumes binary (zero vs. non-zero) input (a mask), so no, it doesn't identify "completely white" pixels, it identifies any non-absolute-black (non-zero) _groups of_ pixels. -- if you want specific ranges of colors or grayscale levels, use `cv::inRange()`, which produces a mask, and *then* apply my answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you can assume the detection target area is white and its shape is (non-rotated) rectangle, simply doing labeling will achieve your detection (because of the assumption : all found white region should be rectangle).

You say you can access pixel data, so, you can implement simple labeling process for this purpose.

Very simple sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct HorizontalLineSeg
{
    int left, right, y;
    HorizontalLineSeg( int left=0, int right=0, int y=0 )
        : left(left), right(right), y(y)
    {}
};

struct RectReg
{
    HorizontalLineSeg Top, Bottom;
    RectReg( const HorizontalLineSeg &Top ) : Top(Top),Bottom(Top) {}
    bool ConnectToBottom( const HorizontalLineSeg &Seg )
    {
        if( Bottom.y+1 != Seg.y )return false;
        if( Seg.right < Bottom.left  ||  Bottom.right < Seg.left )return false;
        Bottom = Seg;
        return true;
    }
};

void Update( std::vector<RectReg> &Regs, const HorizontalLineSeg &FoundSeg )
{
    for( auto &Reg : Regs )
    {
        if( Reg.ConnectToBottom( FoundSeg ) )return;
    }
    Regs.emplace_back( FoundSeg);
}

int main()
{
    //- Load Image as GrayScale
    cv::Mat Img = cv::imread( "WhiteRects.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( Img.empty() ){  std::cout << "imread() failed" << std::endl;    return 0;   }
    //- Find white regions
    std::vector<RectReg> Regs;
    {
        const unsigned char Thresh = 128;
        for( int y=0; y<Img.rows; ++y )
        {
            const unsigned char *p = Img.ptr<unsigned char>( y );
            int FoundLeft = -1;
            for( int x=0; x<Img.cols; ++x, ++p )
            {
                if( *p >= Thresh )
                {
                    if( FoundLeft<0 )FoundLeft = x;
                }
                else if( FoundLeft >= 0 )
                {
                    Update( Regs, HorizontalLineSeg( FoundLeft, x-1, y ) );
                    FoundLeft = -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //- Visualize result
    cv::Mat ShowImg = Img * 0.35;
    if( !Regs.empty() )
    {
        std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > Pts;
        Pts.reserve( Regs.size() );
        for( const auto &Reg : Regs )
        {
            Pts.push_back(
                {
                    { Reg.Top.left, Reg.Top.y },
                    { Reg.Top.right, Reg.Top.y },
                    { Reg.Bottom.right, Reg.Bottom.y },
                    { Reg.Bottom.left, Reg.Bottom.y }
                }
            );
        }
        cv::polylines( ShowImg, Pts, true, cv::Scalar(255) );
    }
    std::cout << Regs.size() << " regs found" << std::endl;
    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Added code that uses OpenCV functions because it seems to be criticized for not using OpenCV functions.

```cpp
int main()
{
    //- Load Image as GrayScale
    cv::Mat Img = cv::imread( "WhiteRects.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
    if( Img.empty() ){  std::cout << "imread() failed" << std::endl;    return 0;   }
    //- Main process with cv::connectedComponentsWithStats()
    cv::Mat Stats;
    int N = 0;
    {
        //- Pre-Binalize with OpenCV's function.
        //  Purpose of this is just to set the background value to 0.
        //  So, if you know the backgroud value is already 0, you can omit this step.
        cv::Mat BinImg;
        cv::threshold( Img, BinImg, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY );
        //- Use connectedComponentsWithStats()
        cv::Mat Labels;  //Only needed to use the function.
        cv::Mat Centroids;  //Only needed to use the function. Or you can use this if you want.
        N = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats( BinImg, Labels, Stats, Centroids );
    }
    //- Visualize result
    cv::Mat ShowImg = Img * 0.35;
    for( int i=1; i<N; ++i )    //be careful not to include 0
    {
        const int *pS = Stats.ptr<int>( i );
        cv::rectangle(
            ShowImg,
            cv::Rect(
                cv::Point{ pS[ cv::CC_STAT_LEFT ],  pS[ cv::CC_STAT_TOP ] },
                cv::Size{ pS[ cv::CC_STAT_WIDTH ],  pS[ cv::CC_STAT_HEIGHT ] }
            ),
            cv::Scalar(255)
        );
    }
    std::cout << N-1 << " regs found" << std::endl; //not N
    cv::imshow( "Result", ShowImg );
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this sample code, `struct RectReg` has only 2 data (top and bottom horizontal line segment) because assuming non-rotated(axis-aligned) rectangle.
If you modify this to keep all line segment data passed to `ConnectToBottom()` method, this code will become to general labeling.

Comment: But, if you want such general labeling, you can try to use OpenCV's function `findContours()`, `connectedComponents()`, etc.

Comment: this answer is significantly more complicated than it needs to be. OpenCV has functions for binarizing images and then picking out the connected components or contours from such a mask.

Comment: I strongly believe that If you don't know C++, you should not evaluate C++ code's "complexity".

Comment: I strongly believe that implementing something from scratch, when OP explicitly asked for OpenCV APIs, *is* more complicated (and not addressing the question). Anyone can evaluate such complexity, even *if* they didn't know C++. My reluctance to present C++ code I wouldn't have tested (I tested my Python code, which is my standard to myself) cannot be construed as "not knowing C++". You should refrain from making such personal claims that are intended to offend.

Comment: OK, now I understood all you said. This inappropriate useless post is not addressing the question.